# PHP ldap_bind is not working on azure with a message can't contact Ldap server

Tags: php, laravel, azure, active-directory

I have a laravel 5 app. With the code below, I am able to successfully authenticate with active directory when on localhost and having the company network cabled plugged to my computer.

```
public static function connect_ldap($username, $password)
{

    $ldapServer = DirectorySetting::where('config_key', 'LdapServerAddress')->value('config_value');
    $conn = ldap_connect($ldapServer, 389);

    if(!$conn) return false;

    ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    $bindServerLDAP = @ldap_bind($conn, $username, $password);

    if(!$bindServerLDAP) return false;

    return $conn;
}
```

How ever, our test and production server is on Microsoft Azure. When I try to authenticate. I get the error below:

```
Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /var/www/html/test_ldap.php on line 70
Error Binding to LDAP: No additional information is available
```

**Observation**

- ldap_connect is successful
- I can successfully ping the ldap server address
- ldap_bind is unsuccessful. Enabling verbose here doesn't help either. It just tells me that No additional information is available
- The system teams says they have created a link between the on premise and azure active dir
- My server is CentOS 7, I have enabled the variables httpd_can_network_connect and httpd_can_connect_ldap like below:

  `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`

  `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_ldap on`

I have equally added in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf, the variable below:

`TLS_REQCERT never`

Even with this, it doesn't work.

What could be wrong?

Comment: The error message is broad and non-specific. But you can try to use LADP client tools like [JXplorer](http://jxplorer.org/) or [LDAP Admin](http://www.ldapadmin.org/) to check whether you've got the right account information and LDAP directory information.

Comment: Also note that LDAP can work on different ports. 389 is LDAP on a single AD domain. 3268 is for AD global catalog. Ports 636 and 3269 are the SSL equivalents.